# Передать данные в форме, и сравнить их с данными в БД

Tags: php, forms

Как реализовать на PHP форму отправки числа от 0 до 9, сравнить это число с числом в базе данных. Если оно соответствует, то происходит переход на следующую станицу.

Пример: index.php с формой, вводим туда число, если соответствует числу в базе, отправляем на следующую станицу, если нет, выводит текст "доступ закрыт".

Comment: Что у вас не получается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все просто

```
<?php
 $per = $_POST['name']; // Переменная, в которой значение с формы
 $query = $dsn->prepare('SELECT Count(*) as count FROM `table_name` WHERE 
 `column_name` = \''.$per.'\' '); // $dsn - переменная, в которой лежит строка подключения
 $query->execute();
 $res = $query->fetch("PDO::FETCH_ASSOC"); // Получаем ассоциативный массив
 if($res['count'] == 1) {
 header("Location: Your_URL");
 } else {
 echo "Ошибка";
 } // Сравниваем значения из бд и выводим результат
?>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за вашу помощь! все получилось.